What is the ordering of qubit basis in QuTip?
Suppose I instantiate a state with 4 qubits in their $|0\rangle$ state with qutip:
from qutip import basis, tensor

state = tensor(*[basis(2,0)]*4)

The output will look like this:
Quantum object: dims=[[2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1]], shape=(16, 1), type='ket', dtype=Dense
Qobj data =
[[1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]

For a machine, this is great. But now I can't tell which component is which. For example, does the second element correspond to $|0001\rangle$? What ordering does QuTip take when writing the vector notation of these states? Does it go from the lowest $|0000\rangle$ to highest $|1111\rangle$ or does it take another approach? Is there a way to print the state in a more human-readable format?

Update:
Apparently, the output is in increasing order because if I do
tensor(basis(2,0),basis(2,1),basis(2,0),basis(2,0))

The output is
Quantum object: dims=[[2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1]], shape=(16, 1), type='ket', dtype=Dense
Qobj data =
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [1.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]

Which is on the fourth place, as it would be expected if it was in increasing order.

The closest thing I got from a human-readable response was this:
import tabulate
from qutip import basis, tensor

ψ = tensor(*[basis(2,0)]*4)

rows = []
for j in range(2**4):
    if ψ[j][0] != 0:
        rows.append({
            "state": f"{j:04b}",
            "amplitude": f"{np.real(ψ[j][0])} + j{np.imag(ψ[j][0])}"
        })

print(tabulate.tabulate(rows, headers="keys"))

Should output:
  state  amplitude
-------  -----------
   0000  1.0 + j0.0

I will leave the question open if someone has a better approach.

Suppose we are talking about computational basis states only. For $n$-qubits states, these are vectors with dimension $2^n$ and are composed of one "1" component whereas others are zero. A position of "1" specify which basis state is represented by the vector. If "1" is on $i$th position, then the vector corresponds to state $|i-1\rangle$. Number $i-1$ has to be converted to binary.
For example, if three-qubit state is written as $(0\,0\,0\,0\,1\,0\,0\,0)$, then "1" is on fifth place ($i=5$), hence it is the state corresponding to number 4, in binary 100, so the equivalent basis state is $|100\rangle$.
And here is Python code allowing to convert a basis state expressed as an array to human readable form:
import numpy as np
import math as m
import cmath as cm

#general state in vector form to Dirac notation
def vectorToDirac (state):
    result = ''
    state = state / np.linalg.norm(state,2) #state normalization
    stateDim = int(m.log(len(state),2))
    
    k = 0
    for i in range(0,len(state)):
        if state[i] <> 0:   
            if k > 0: result = result + ' + ' 
            
            result = result +  str(abs(state[i])) #abs. of probability aplitude
            
            #basis state phase            
            if cm.phase(state[i]) <> 0: result = result + ' EXP[' + str(cm.phase(state[i])) + 'i]'
            
            result = result + '|' + bin(i).replace('0b','').zfill(stateDim) + '>'                 
            
            #go to new line to have better readability of the output
            k = k + 1
            if k % 2 == 0: result = result + '\n'
                
    return result

#print basis state in readable form
qubits = 3 # number of qubits
basisStates = 2**qubits

state = np.zeros([1,2**qubits])

#print all basis state in vector and readable forms
for i in range(0,basisStates):     
    if i == 0:
        state[0][0] = 1
    else:
        state[0][i - 1] = 0
        state[0][i] = 1
    print(str(state) + ' => ' + vectorToDirac(state[0]))   

#normalize and print general state (from vector to Dirac notation)
print('\n')
state = np.array([-1+1j,1,1-1j,1+1j])
print vectorToDirac(state)

